# How to use local docker image in ha kubeadm Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Searching the web for *how to deploy a locally build docker image in kubernetes*, I found solutions in combination with **minikube** only.

For example: [minikube](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d)

So I'm wondering, is it possible to use locally build docker images in an Kubernetes Cluster established by `kubeadm` or is the preferred way to deploy those images to an private registry and pull it afterwards from within the cluster?

Comment: Private registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a private registry is definitely the way to do it. Some may rely on a third-party registry, others would deploy it in kubernetes. Solutions may include Artifactory, Nexus, Portus, Harbor, GitLab, docker-registry, ... most of which may use s3 storage and would scale horizontally.

Now, with minikube, hosting a registry might not be practical: you could indeed build your images directly on your host. But you shouldn't do this anywhere else.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for that detailed answer!

Comment: Can you please point out how to use  docker registry in a cluster setup using kubeadm

Comment: It depends on your runtime (docker, crio, containerd, ...), the way your registry is deployed (tls,or not, is there a CA). A good starting point might be kubespray playbooks, which covers pretty much all uses cases. See https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray